# How to store JWT token response from dynamo

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, jwt, serverless-framework

I have stored my JWT token in dynamodb, from a step function used to generate it.

I have fetched the token using api gateway to my static site hosted in s3.

Does anyone know how to save it in cookie?

I am using the serverless framework to deploy my lambdas, if that is any help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To save this (or anything else, really) in a cookie, you need to either respond to a browser request with `Set-Cookie` HTTP header, see:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie

or to set it with client-side JavaScript, see:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie

How you do it exactly depends on:

1. do you want to set it with HTTP headers or client-side JavaScript?
2. what framework do you use?
3. how your application is accessed?
4. how do you want to use that cookie?

Remember that cookie is client-side state and all you tell us about is how you get the data that you want to be stored in a cookie (which doesn't matter) and not how the client-server interaction is done (which is what matters here).